# How to plot the 3D function in python using max( ) function

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

I am trying to plot a 3d  surface with a,b as the variables and f(a,b) as the function which can be defined as:

```
def fun(a, b):
    y=[2.1,2.9,3.8, 5.3]
    t=[0,1,2,4]
    s=[0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(4):
      s[i]=abs(y[i]-a*t[i]-b)
    return max(s)
```

Individually, this function is giving the expected output without error, when I just call

```
print( fun(1,2))
>>>0.7000000000000002
```

But when I do the exact same thing while trying to plot a 3D graph, I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here is my full code to plot the graph:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(a, b):
    y=[2.1,2.9,3.8, 5.3]
    t=[0,1,2,4]
    s=[0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(4):
      s[i]=abs(y[i]-a*t[i]-b)
    return max(s)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
a = np.arange(-1,3,0.01)
b = np.arange(-1,2,0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(a, b)
zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
Z= zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('a')
ax.set_ylabel('b')
ax.set_zlabel('f(a,b)')
plt.show()
```

And this is the exact error that I am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-db5afaaa5285> in <module>()
     16 b = np.arange(-1,2,0.01)
     17 X, Y = np.meshgrid(a, b)
---> 18 zs = np.array(fun(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
     19 Z= zs.reshape(X.shape)
     20 

<ipython-input-82-db5afaaa5285> in fun(a, b)
      9     for i in range(4):
     10       s[i]=abs(y[i]-a*t[i]-b)
---> 11     return max(s)
     12 
     13 fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `s` has a shape `(4, 300, 400)`. When you do `return max(s)`, which maximum do you want? You will have to specify the axis on which the maximum is calculated, using `return np.max(s, axis=...)`.

Comment: I dont  understand why `s` would have a shape `(4,300,400)`. I am initializing `s` to be of a 1D list as `[0,0,0,0]`, so I assume it would have a shape of `(4)`. Please help me understand here. I just want to calculate the value of the function by sending different values of `a,b`. For every unique set of (a,b) that I send, I would get 4 different answers, which I am storing in `s[i]`. So the function should just return the max of those 4 values, as it does when I am running it alone. Please help me here

Comment: I used the suggestion given by @Guimoute and changed my `max(s)` to `np.max(s,axis=0)` and it worked like a magic. Thank you. But I still don't understand why did s change its shape?

Comment: `abs(y[i]-a*t[i]-b)` both `a` and `b` are long arrays. At every index of `s`, you're placing an array, not a single value. Also you can do `X.ravel()` and `Y.ravel()`